# Problem involving modular arithmetic.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $\gcd(a, 11) = 1$. If $3a^7 \equiv 5 \pmod{11}$, show that $a \equiv 3 \pmod{11}$.

My first approach was to use Euler's theorem:

$a^{10} \equiv 1 \pmod{11}$

$3a^7  \equiv 5 \pmod{11}$ implies that $a^{-3} \equiv 9 \pmod{11}$

I feel i'm not on the right track, hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

in $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$ we have that $5^{-1} = 9 = -2$ and as you said, $a^{10} = 1$ if and only if $a \neq 0$, but $0$ is not a solution so we can go on.

$$ 3 a^7 = 5 \quad \Rightarrow \quad  3 \cdot 9 \cdot a^{10} = a^3 \quad \Rightarrow \quad 5 = a^3$$

Comupting cubes is a little boring, but you only have to do half work since $\forall b \in \mathbb{Z}_{11} \quad b^3 = -(-b)^3 = -(11-b)^3$ so we do
$$ 1^3 = 1 \quad 2^3 = 8 \quad 3^3 = 5 \quad 4^3 = 9 \quad 5^3 = 4 $$
And we know without any effort that
$$ 10^3 = -1 \quad 9^3 = -8 \quad 8^3 = -5 \quad 7^3 = -9 \quad 6^3 = -4$$

Thus, $a = 3$ is the only solution

Comment: "Comupting cubes is a little boring"  Is there an algorithm for cube roots?  There's euclids algorithm for doing division, but is there an equivalent for roots.  In this case we had already been doing things with 3.9 = 27= 5 so we should have $3^3 = 27 =5$ in mind.

Comment: yep, but the point is that you have to prove that $3$ is the only solution. This can be by the way done by prooving that in $\mathbb{Z}$ the function $\varphi: \mathbb{Z}^*_{11} \to  \mathbb{Z}^*_{11}$ such that $\varphi(x) = x^3$ must be a bijection. It is so since if you call $G$ it's immage it's not so difficult to prove that $[\mathbb{Z}^*_{11}:G] \in \{1, 3\} $, but it cannot be $3$ since the order of $\mathbb{Z}^*_{11}$ is 10. So the function is bijective and the solution is always unique

Comment: If $a^3 = b^3$ then $a^9 = a^{-1} = b^9= b^{-1}$ are distinct and $a = b$ as $\mathbb Z_{11}^*$ is a field.  That never seemed the issue.  The question I have is can we find $\sqrt[n]{m}$ in $\mathbb Z_p^*$ in any other way than trial and error?

Answer (score 0):

Multiply both sides by $4$ to find

$$a^7\equiv20\pmod{11}\equiv9$$

Now $a^1=(a^7)^3\cdot(a^{10})^{-2}$

$$\equiv9^3(1)^{-2}\equiv(-2)^3\pmod{11}\equiv?$$

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right track.

$3a^7 \equiv 5\mod 11$

$3a^{-3} \equiv 5 \mod 11$

$a^{-3} \equiv 3^{-1}*5 \mod 11$

$a^3 \equiv 3*5^{-1} \mod 11$

$a \equiv \sqrt[3]{3*5^{-1}} \mod 11$.

Somehow you figure $3^{-1}*5 \equiv 9 \mod 11$, and I can't argue with that.  $9*3 = 27\equiv 5$ so that is true.

So $a^{-3} \equiv 3^{-1}*5 \equiv 9\mod 11$ so

$a^3 \equiv 3*5^{-1} \equiv 9^{-1} \mod 11$.  So as $9*5 =45\equiv 1$, or because $5*9 =45\equiv 1$ and $3*9 = 27\equiv 5 \mod 11$ we have $9^{-1} \equiv 5$ and $3*5^{-1}\equiv 3*9\equiv 5$.

So $a^3 \equiv 5 \equiv 27 \mod 11$ so $a \equiv 3 \equiv \sqrt[3]{27} \mod 11$.

The only thing I feel uncomfortable about us finding $m^{-1}$ and $\sqrt[n] m$ wer a matter of guessing.  $m^{-1}$ can have all the guesswork removed by euclid's algorithm.  There's probably a way to take the guesswork out of $\sqrt[n] m$ as well.

the quick way to get the cube roots are by listing; $(\pm 1)^3 \equiv \pm 1$, $(\pm 2)^3 \equiv \pm 8 \equiv \mp 3$, $(\pm 3)^2 \equiv \pm 27 \equiv \pm 5$, $(\pm 4)^3 \equiv \pm 64 \equiv \mp 2$, $(\pm 5)^3 \equiv \pm 125 \pm 4$.

So $\sqrt[3]{\pm 1} = \pm 1;\sqrt[3]{\pm 2} = \mp 4\equiv \pm 7;\sqrt[3]{\pm 3}=\mp 2\equiv \pm 9$; $\sqrt[3]{\pm 4} = \pm 5; \sqrt[3]{\pm 5}=\pm 3;$